# How to keep dashed lines from "dancing" in OpenGl?

Tags: opengl

I'm drawing some lines in OpenGL (from C) using code like this:

```
glLineStipple(6, 0xEEEE);
glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

glVertex2f(x, y);
...
```

It works great if everything is still. However, my problem is that as soon as I zoom in or out the line starts shimmering. I mean that the location of the dashes in the line move around. It looks very sloppy.

Is there someway to anchor how the line is dashed in model space? I think my issue is that `glLineStipple()` look at the number of pixels drawn, but I'd like it to look at the length in model space instead.

Comment: Use a shader. `glLineStipple` is old and deprecated, and a shader gives you much more control over things like this.

Comment: I agree with the above. I'd write such a shader as an answer, but my OpenGL testing environment is currently broken. A shader is definitely the way to go. Avoiding fixed-function is strongly suggested in general.

Comment: Can somebody post an answer with an example of using a shader for this? I've never done a shader and all the tutorials online are using them with triangles, not lines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Texture the line instead of using stipple and alpha blend. I´d prefer mirror wrapping mode for the texture but repeat would work just as well depedning on the pattern. Use alpha test to remove coverage causing artifact, if any. Put texture coordinates on the line just as any polygon.

No shader required.